# ZeroRPC bind multi-port for process

Tags: python

I want to bind multi-port at server and wait client connect. After I bind more than one port. The first port is okay, but the second port client can not connect. The below are my sample code.

```
class HelloRPC(object):
  def hello(self, name):
        print   "this is server"
        return "Hello"
s = zerorpc.Server(HelloRPC())
s.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:4242")

s1 = zerorpc.Server(HelloRPC())
s1.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:5000")

s.run()
s1.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call for s.run() blocks, preventing you from being able to get to s1.run().

One way to deal with this is to use [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) to spawn multiple greenlets to run the server:

```
import zerorpc
import gevent


class HelloRPC(object):
    def hello(self, name):
        print "this is server"
        return "Hello"

s = zerorpc.Server(HelloRPC())
s.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5001")

s1 = zerorpc.Server(HelloRPC())
s1.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5002")

gevent.joinall([gevent.spawn(s.run), gevent.spawn(s1.run)])
```

With that, you can run:

```
> zerorpc tcp://127.0.0.1:5002 hello world
connecting to "tcp://127.0.0.1:5002"
'Hello'
> zerorpc tcp://127.0.0.1:5001 hello world
connecting to "tcp://127.0.0.1:5001"
'Hello'
```

Check out the ZeroRPC [tests](https://github.com/dotcloud/zerorpc-python/tree/master/tests) for more examples of how to run multiple servers.

Answer (score -1):

You can also create just one server instance and bind it to several ports as follows:

```
class HelloRPC(object):
  def hello(self, name):
        print   "this is server"
        return "Hello"
s = zerorpc.Server(HelloRPC())
s.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:4242")
s.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:5000")

s.run()
```

Note that this is different than the example that you provided. While in your example, two clients connecting to different ports will interact with distinct instances of the HelloRPC class, in my example they will interact with the same HelloRPC instance.

Comment: The code is wrong, `s1` variable is undefined in this case.

Comment: You're right, it should be ``s``, not ``s1``. I updated the answer.